# how to show a success dialog box after filling the newSuccess.php form?

Tags: php, symfony1, dialog, symfony-1.4

I need to put a dialog box saying something like "success!" after someone fill a `newSuccess.php` form. How can I do it?

Comment: You want to add this message after submitting form? or...?

Comment: when the user click in the submit button I want something like that to show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flash massages. You can read about [**it**](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/13).You also can use this [**plugin**](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFlashMessagePlugin) 
Or after submitting you can redirect to custom action, when your form valid.

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
    {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $this->redirect('yourmodule/success');
    }
```

Comment: I was looking for something like an alert in ajax but this is good too. thank you. by the way, do you know how to do it in ajax? thanks again